# spring cache - Null key returned for cache operation

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have been working with Spring Cache Abstraction and `Ehcache`. I'm using the `@Cacheable` annotation on a target method like so:

```
@Component
public class DataService {
    @Cacheable(value="movieFindCache", key="#name")
    public String findByDirector(String name) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

This is my jUnit test:

```
public class ServiceTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Resource
    private DataService dataService;

    @Test
    public void test_service() {
        System.err.println(dataService.findByDirector("Hello"));
    }
}
```

This is not working fine when I debug with jUnit test. It throws an `IllegalArgumentException` as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?) CacheableOperation[public java.lang.String com.eliteams.quick4j.web.service.ExcelDataService.getCarData()] caches=[movieFindCache] | key='#name' | condition='' | unless=''
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:315)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.collectPutRequests(CacheAspectSupport.java:265)
```

I have the following config:

applicationContext.xml:

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager"/>
<bean id="ehCacheManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
      p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml" p:shared="true"/>
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
      p:cacheManager-ref="ehCacheManagerFactory"/>
```

ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="true"
     monitoring="autodetect"
     dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

<cache name="movieFindCache"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
       eternal="false"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>
```

note: If I don't specify the "key" in the `@Cacheable` annotations, it works.

Is there anything I forgot to specify? config? annotations?

Comment: You don't really need to specify the key if there is only one argument

Comment: could you add the test?

Comment: you miss the parameter at `dataService.findByDirector()`

Comment: which  parameter, please?

Comment: @GreenLei `System.err.println(dataService.findByDirector());` you don't pass any `name` parameter to the method. It should be `System.err.println(dataService.findByDirector("John smith"));` for example

Comment: Thanks, I miss the parameter when edit my question. I added it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you could try to replace key with #p0

```
@Component
public class DataService {
    @Cacheable(value="movieFindCache", key="#p0")
    public String findByDirector(String name) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

reference from
[Spring Cache Abstraction VS interfaces VS key param ("Null key returned for cache operation" error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197359/spring-cache-abstraction-vs-interfaces-vs-key-param-null-key-returned-for-cach)

Answer (score 19):

Had the same problem, root cause was that in tests parameter was really null, so, just added not null check

```
@Cacheable(value="movieFindCache", key="#p0", condition="#p0!=null")
public String findByDirector(String name) {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen using ehCache 3.  It worked fine in my local environment using the parameter name as the key, for instance:

```
// this would fail
@Cacheable(value="movieFindCache", key="name")
    public String findByDirector(String name) {
```

but when deployed in a test environment I would receive the error.  I resolved this by removing the key property from the @Cacheable annotation for methods with a single parameter:

```
// this worked
@Cacheable("movieFindCache")
    public String findByDirector(String name) {
```

Answer (score -3):

The message of the `IllegalArgumentException` is pretty explicit. The [following table](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context) in the spring documentation indicates what is available for using argument names.

And the relevant [`javac` options are documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options). You want the `-g` ones in this context.

Comment: The link to "following table" does not refer to a table.